# IS there any way to pass variable while creating table in database?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to dynamically create table from my program with columns name and table name given by me through my program. so i want to pass my variable to the stored procedure but error occurs as i do like this

```
create procedure maketable
@name varchar(50),
@roll int
as 
begin
create table new  (@name, @roll)
end
```

error is as follow

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure maketable, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '@name'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck, [MySQL stored procedures can not contain dynamic SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html), and the variable implementation can't be used how you're trying to use it.

Because you know all of the column information in your calling code, is there a specific reason you can't just issue the `CREATE TABLE` directly from your code?  That would be the most straightforward way to get this done.  (Mind you, having non-temporary tables spring into existence on demand is probably a bad, bad idea...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start - this creates a table with one field so you should be able to finish it off:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS maketable;

delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE maketable (IN table_name varchar(50), IN field1Name varchar(50), IN field1Type varchar(50))
BEGIN
   SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', table_name, '(', field1Name, ' ', field1Type, ')');
   PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
   EXECUTE stmt1;
END//
delimiter ;

CALL maketable('tst', 'id', 'INT');
```

Comment: And also 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? It worked when I tested it on 5.1

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure maketable, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure maketable, Line 3
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.